# How do I make a cells value equal the subtotal of a filterable column in a pivot table without including the autocalculated total value at the bottom

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to link a cell to display the subtotal of a column within a pivot table. I want to be able to filter using a slicer and have the number change along with the data, however it keeps adding the subtotal from the Pivot table into the equation. [image]
In the picture- I'd like D3 to reflect the subtotal of column D without including the total in cell D12 - where i'm having issues is, if I select a different name in the slicer the cell moves from D12 to as many data points as there are.